# onbeforeunload auto click submit button

Tags: javascript, html

How to make it work, couse now it won't work. I want to auto click button if detect website close.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("makeOffline").click();
    }
</script>
<body onbeforeunload="return myFunction()">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will call your function. But the things your function is allowed to do, in a modern browser, are **very** limited. You can't, to pick a random example, submit a form.

In general, the only useful use case for `onbeforeunload` is to warn users that they may lose data if they leave the page, which you can do by returning a string from your handler. The browser will then check with the user to see if they really want to leave (most of them will show the string you return, but not all — Firefox doesn't anymore, for instance).

Anything else you might be trying to do in an `onbeforeunload` handler is almost certainly better suited to being done some other way. If you post a question about your end goal, people may be able to help you with it.

Comment: Thanks for information, so maybe i can check and return string text if only website want close (except refresh and link click)?

Comment: @Rob: Refresh and link clicks fire `onbeforeunload` too.

Comment: Maybe know other ability?